# How to install any Python package once and then reuse it in Databricks V2?

Tags: python, databricks

In my office, in Databricks V1, I found that there are some Python packages which are not built-in, but is imported to the notebook. Then I went to the cluster settings, but didn't find any package there [I saw the cluster settings since some jar file was installed there for future use. So I thought that Python packages may be treated with same way.].

But, in Databricks V2, in the notebook, there are some installation commands '%pip install ...'. After running the notebook first time, I removed those installation commands, and reran it. But it failed as there is no packages installed.

My question is, then where does the installed files go when I run '%pip install' in V2? Can I create a global sharable space for the installation files, and then use that storage in all notebooks in V2? I don't want to use the installation commands again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Databricks, every time you start a cluster, it is created from scratch, and doesn't "remember" what you installed in the previouse sessions.

To have those libraries available each time, you can leave the pip install command in the beggining of your code, or use cluster libraries to pre-install them. Instruction here: https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/cluster-libraries.html